# if $G$ is a EDP of two finite groups A and B. then order of element $(a,b)\in G=A\times B$ is lcm of order of a and order of b.

Tags: finite-groups

If $G$  is a external direct product of two finite groups $A$ and $B$, then order of element $(a,b)\in G=A\times B$  is lcm of order of $a$ and order of $b$.

Comment: So it is. Did you have any question you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 1):

Consider when is it that $(a, b)^{n} = (a^{n}, b^{n}) = (1, 1)$.